# Reading contents of nested tables in word doc in python

Tags: python, ms-word, openxml, python-docx

I have a word document that consists of tables nested within tables and im trying to read it with python-doc but reading it often results in multiple duplicates of almost all the text.

For example im currently using:

```
for table in docfile.tables:
     for row in table.rows:
          for cell in row.cells:
               data.append(cell.text)
```

This results in texts that only show up 17 times being printed 100+ times in my list, or other text that only shows 3 times in the doc being printed 10+ times. Is there any way to properly extract the data in nested tables?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are seeing that particular problem, but to deal with the nesting issue you could use a recursive function. For example...

```
def process_table(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(cell.text)
            for subtable in cell.tables:
                process_table(subtable)

for table in document.tables:
    process_table(table)
```

Here, with a very simple sample document, that code processes each top-level table. For each table, it processes each row, and each cell within the row. For each cell, it prints any text *outside* any nested tables that may be in the cell, then processes the first table in the cell, if any, and so on.

If you try that and you still get repeated texts, that suggests that there is another problem. For example, my simple test data had tables that had no merged columns or rows.

Also. I thought there used to be a fairly small maximum number of nesting levels for tables. But now it seems to be possible to nest at least 20 levels. The Word documentation does not list a limit. One consequence is that you might want to modify the recursive function so that it stops processing after a specified number of levels.

TBH I doubt if a Word document with even 4, or possibly 3, nested table levels would be particularly easy for a human to read anyway.